# Rust: Poor runtime performance on Ubuntu with Core i9 compared to MacOS with Core i7

Tags: performance, rust, runtime

I'm facing a weird issue when measuring runtime performance of a Rust binary crate.
The crate is the [xdevs simulator](https://github.com/iscar-ucm/xdevs.rs).
To run it you only need to clone the git repo:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/iscar-ucm/xdevs.rs.git
cd xdevs.rs
cargo run --release HO 200 200
```

On a MacBook Pro with MacOS Moterey and a 2.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 processor, I get this output:

```
Model creation time: 110.71127ms
Simulator creation time: 121ns
Simulation time: 991.374624ms
```

However, when trying on a workstation PC with Ubuntu 20.04 and an Intel Core i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70GHz, I get this output:

```
Model creation time: 61.938331ms
Simulator creation time: 137ns
Simulation time: 2.737863127s
```

This makes no sense to me. Why do I get worse results using a more powerful machine?
By the way, I'm enabling link time optimization and using the target-cpu=native flag when compiling.

---

**EDIT:**

I thought it would be a good idea to add more information about the properties of the toolchain etc in each machine.

On Mac:

```bash
➜  xdevs.rs git:(main) rustc --version
rustc 1.66.0 (69f9c33d7 2022-12-12)
➜  xdevs.rs git:(main) rustc -C target-cpu=native --print cfg
debug_assertions
panic="unwind"
target_arch="x86_64"
target_endian="little"
target_env=""
target_family="unix"
target_feature="aes"
target_feature="avx"
target_feature="avx2"
target_feature="bmi1"
target_feature="bmi2"
target_feature="fma"
target_feature="fxsr"
target_feature="lzcnt"
target_feature="pclmulqdq"
target_feature="popcnt"
target_feature="rdrand"
target_feature="sse"
target_feature="sse2"
target_feature="sse3"
target_feature="sse4.1"
target_feature="sse4.2"
target_feature="ssse3"
target_feature="xsave"
target_feature="xsaveopt"
target_has_atomic="128"
target_has_atomic="16"
target_has_atomic="32"
target_has_atomic="64"
target_has_atomic="8"
target_has_atomic="ptr"
target_os="macos"
target_pointer_width="64"
target_vendor="apple"
unix
```

On Ubuntu:

```bash
rcardenas@celsius:~/xdevs.rs$ rustc --version
rustc 1.66.0 (69f9c33d7 2022-12-12)
rcardenas@celsius:~/xdevs.rs$ rustc -C target-cpu=native --print cfg
debug_assertions
panic="unwind"
target_arch="x86_64"
target_endian="little"
target_env="gnu"
target_family="unix"
target_feature="adx"
target_feature="aes"
target_feature="avx"
target_feature="avx2"
target_feature="bmi1"
target_feature="bmi2"
target_feature="fma"
target_feature="fxsr"
target_feature="lzcnt"
target_feature="pclmulqdq"
target_feature="popcnt"
target_feature="rdrand"
target_feature="rdseed"
target_feature="sse"
target_feature="sse2"
target_feature="sse3"
target_feature="sse4.1"
target_feature="sse4.2"
target_feature="ssse3"
target_feature="xsave"
target_feature="xsavec"
target_feature="xsaveopt"
target_feature="xsaves"
target_has_atomic="16"
target_has_atomic="32"
target_has_atomic="64"
target_has_atomic="8"
target_has_atomic="ptr"
target_os="linux"
target_pointer_width="64"
target_vendor="unknown"
unix
```

However, I still don't understand why Ubuntu takes three times more to simulate than MacOs, when Ubuntu has way better hardware specifications.

---

**EDIT**
I want to add the outcome when I run the crate in release mode in Mac:

```bash
➜  xdevs.rs git:(main) RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo run --verbose --release HO 200 200
   Compiling xdevs v0.1.1 (/Users/rcardenas/xdevs.rs)
     Running `rustc --crate-name xdevs --edition=2021 src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=8d925d6ed50d8948 -C extra-filename=-8d925d6ed50d8948 --out-dir /Users/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps -L dependency=/Users/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps -C target-cpu=native`
     Running `rustc --crate-name xdevs --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=7179874cf29eab82 -C extra-filename=-7179874cf29eab82 --out-dir /Users/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps -L dependency=/Users/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps --extern xdevs=/Users/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps/libxdevs-8d925d6ed50d8948.rlib -C target-cpu=native`
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.87s
     Running `target/release/xdevs HO 200 200`
Model creation time: 99.400995ms
Simulator creation time: 66ns
Simulation time: 840.980883ms
```

In Ubuntu:

```bash
rcardenas@celsius:~/xdevs.rs$ RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo run --verbose --release HO 200 200
   Compiling xdevs v0.1.1 (/home/rcardenas/xdevs.rs)
     Running `rustc --crate-name xdevs --edition=2021 src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=f8b9c1c6a690ac7c -C extra-filename=-f8b9c1c6a690ac7c --out-dir /home/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps -L dependency=/home/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps -C target-cpu=native`
     Running `rustc --crate-name xdevs --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=1a0bd9ecd09448cd -C extra-filename=-1a0bd9ecd09448cd --out-dir /home/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps -L dependency=/home/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps --extern xdevs=/home/rcardenas/xdevs.rs/target/release/deps/libxdevs-f8b9c1c6a690ac7c.rlib -C target-cpu=native`
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.96s
     Running `target/release/xdevs HO 200 200`
Model creation time: 69.743935ms
Simulator creation time: 121ns
Simulation time: 2.782144931s
```

Comment: Note that your `--print cfg` doesn't account for the `target-cpu=native`. Can you run `rustc -C target-cpu=native --print cfg` on both machines?

Comment: Sure! I edited my question as requested

Comment: Strange, the only difference that could affect performance is `target_has_atomic="128"`, except that it shouldn't matter since the code is single threaded. If you `cargo clean` and `cargo build --release --verbose`, does the `target-cpu=native` option really get passed to `rustc`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I included to the end of my question the outcome for both compilations

Comment: Regatding the atomic stuff. The code used refcells a lot, maybe that is one of the principal reasons of such a performance difference?

Comment: AFAIK refcells don't use atomics, and even if they did they wouldn't use 128-bit atomics.

Comment: True. I developed a quick alternative with raw pointers and unsafe stuff instead of RefCells and got a slightly slower solution in both machines. So, it seems that RefCells are not the problem here. I'll try to check the intermediate LLVM outcome in both machines, but currently I don't know how to compare them

Comment: You're measuring wall-time there. First figure out whether where it's spending time (IO? kernel? userspace?) and whether it parallelizes the same (if it's multi-threaded). If it's almost entirely cpu-bound run under `perf stat` and `perf record` and whatever the macos equivalents are and compare.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe two platforms debug mode optimization are different,
does you tried `cargo --release` to build in release mode.

---

Sorry, I didn't notice the `--release`, I tried on my notebook(`archlinux ryzen 4800U`):

```
[I] forks@archlinux /t/xdevs.rs (main)> target/release/xdevs HO 200 200
Model creation time: 67.439928ms
Simulator creation time: 1.396µs
Simulation time: 2.061134191s
```

And on my PC (`archlinux ryzen 1700x`) get similar result:

```
*[main][/tmp/xdevs.rs]$ target/release/xdevs HO 200 200
Model creation time: 89.505405ms
Simulator creation time: 80ns
Simulation time: 2.039591205s
```

Toolchain? cpu schedule? I tried `HO 200 2000`:

```
[I] forks@archlinux /t/xdevs.rs (main)> time target/release/xdevs HO 200 2000
Model creation time: 606.153956ms
Simulator creation time: 1.467µs
Simulation time: 21.079952693s
```

and

```
*[main][/tmp/xdevs.rs]$ target/release/xdevs HO 200 2000
Model creation time: 685.050164ms
Simulator creation time: 40ns
Simulation time: 21.746809784s
```

Identical result

Comment: According to the commands in the question, the OP is already running in release mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm running the crate in release mode with O3

Comment: That's weird it seems that your results are similar to the ones obtained by my Ubuntu machine. I edited my question and added information about the Rust compiler version and the configurations that it uses when compiling. Hopefully someone notices something that makes the difference between MacOS and Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: I also enabled `lto`, and `target-cpu=native`

Comment: Maybe the code, does not contains advanced feature (such as avx, sse etc) that compiler or cpu can optimize, so different cpu gives similar result. Oddly not related to cpu freq,

Comment: The code contains multiple refcells. That is the only thing I imagine could make the difference. However, a priori I would always say that a Linux system would perform better than Mac or Windows. These results surprise me